# Hibernate/JPA not creating tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I'm running an Java EE application on Wildfly 15.0.1. I'm trying to use JPA without creating datasource on wildfly, because I want all the dependencies to be packed in application source code. I am using Maven to build the WAR.

I am using PostgreSQL and it's up and running on http://localhost:5432 I create db called testing for this project.

So, I added this dependency to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

My persistence.xml is in `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.2"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="pu1">
    <!-- classes -->
    <class>myapp.model.Address</class>
    <class>myapp.model.Transaction</class>
    <properties>
        <!-- database connection -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testing" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="postgres" />

        <!-- hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I have *@Entity* annotation on both my Address and Transaction classes. But, nothing happens. Here's the log snippet:

```
22:58:05,759 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 103) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: pu1
    ...]
22:58:05,760 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment myapp.backend-1.0.war
22:58:05,791 WARN  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYRS0018: Explicit usage of Jackson annotation in a JAX-RS deployment; the system will disable JSON-B processing for the current deployment. Consider setting the 'resteasy.preferJacksonOverJsonB' property to 'false' to restore JSON-B.
22:58:05,796 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 42.2)
22:58:05,810 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = myapp.backend-1.0.war_org.postgresql.Driver_42_2
22:58:05,816 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 103) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'myapp.backend-1.0.war#pu1'
22:58:05,817 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 103) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
22:58:05,820 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 103) HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@6543510a
22:58:05,822 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 103) Envers integration enabled? : true
22:58:05,858 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 103) HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@4cc01a34'
22:58:05,858 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 103) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

Answer (score 2):

JPA specification:

8.2.1.2 transaction-type

> The transaction-type attribute is used to specify whether the entity
>   managers provided by the entity manager factory for the persistence
>   unit must be JTA entity managers or resource-local entity managers.
>   The value of this element is JTA or RESOURCE_LOCAL. A transaction-type
>   of JTA assumes that a JTA data source will be provided—either as
>   specified by the jta-data-source element or provided by the container.
>   In general, in Java EE environments, a transaction-type of
>   RESOURCE_LOCAL assumes that a non-JTA datasource will be provided. In
>   a Java EE environment, if this element is not specified, the default
>   is JTA. In a Java SE environment, if this element is not specified,
>   the default is RESOURCE_LOCAL.

JTA is default transaction type in EE application server. To use it you need a datasource configured in WildFly. Then add it to persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="pu1" transaction-type="JTA">
    <!-- classes -->
    <class>myapp.model.Address</class>
    <class>myapp.model.Transaction</class>
    <properties>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/jndi_name_of_datasource</jta-data-source>

        <!-- hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```